# How do I read a soap response with simplexml_load_string()

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse a soap response with simplexml_load_string(). I have my soap client set with trace = 1 and exceptions = 0 and $client->__getLastResponse() gives me this result:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<MDHeader>
<userid>inspector@prime.com</userid>
<password>prime123456</password>
<batchid>1234</batchid></MDHeader>
<RECORDSET>
<ROW id='0'>
<INSPECTIONS>
<FOLDER_ID>835410936</FOLDER_ID>
<FOLDER_ID>835221706</FOLDER_ID>
<FOLDER_ID>835222299</FOLDER_ID>
</INSPECTIONS>
</ROW>
</RECORDSET>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I then read the results into  $xml:

```
$xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";
$xml .= urldecode($client->__getLastResponse());
```

An finally try to echo an element with no luck:

```
$xml1 = simplexml_load_string($xml,null,null,'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',true);
echo "ELEMENT:" . $xml1->Envelope->Body->MDHeader->userid;
```

I believe it is the namespace SOAP-ENV that is giving me the issue but I don't know how to resolve it.

You can see my test page at: http://www.primevaluationservices.com/myriad/test.php

Comment: if you are using PHP to call like `$response = $client->doFunction($params);` or something, won't $response already be an object with that XML parsed?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need this line because it is already in the xml:

`$xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";`

To get the 'userid', I think you can use the SimpleXMLElement [children](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.children) method:

```
$source = <<<SOURCE
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<MDHeader>
<userid>inspector@prime.com</userid>
<password>prime123456</password>
<batchid>1234</batchid></MDHeader>
<RECORDSET>
<ROW id='0'>
<INSPECTIONS>
<FOLDER_ID>835410936</FOLDER_ID>
<FOLDER_ID>835221706</FOLDER_ID>
<FOLDER_ID>835222299</FOLDER_ID>
</INSPECTIONS>
</ROW>
</RECORDSET>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
SOURCE;
$xml1 = simplexml_load_string($source);

echo $xml1->children('SOAP-ENV', true)->Body->children('')->MDHeader->userid->__toString();
```

Or the SimpleXMLElement [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) method:

```
$elements = $xml1->xpath('//SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/MDHeader/userid');
$userid = $elements[0]->__toString();
echo '<br>';
echo $userid;
```

Will both result in:

> inspector@prime.com

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/RJiGS)